# Refresh data on vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This may have been asked but I have not be able to find a solution.  I have a index page that loads a left nav vue.  On that view is a typeahead input with names.  When a name is selected a function is called and and a unique value is passed as the pmid_list

```
        this.$router.push({ name: 'About', params: { pmid_list: item.PMID_Include } }
```

This works fine the first time because the About vue is loaded and the function is called with the pmid_list value.  Every name works fine if I refresh the page between calls.  If I don't refresh the correct pmid_list (parameter) is sent to the router but the router decides to send the old one if the vue component has not changed.

From what I have read it is a router issue but I can't figure out how to force it to refresh.

```
           export default new Router({
           mode: 'history',
           routes: [
                 {
                   path: '/about/:pmid_list',
                   name: 'About',
                   component: About,
                   props: {default: true}
                   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `About` component is being cached.

> One thing to note when using routes with params is that when the user navigates from /user/foo to /user/bar, **the same component instance will be reused.** Since both routes render the same component, this is more efficient than destroying the old instance and then creating a new one. **However, this also means that the lifecycle hooks of the component will not be called.**

[Dynamic Route Matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)

As shown in the documentation, you should use a `watcher` to react to parameter changes:

```
watch: {
  '$route' (to, from) {
    // react to route changes...
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is only a small part of the solution.  I had read the documentation before I asked the question but the documentation is only half an answer.  I had to watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
       this.getPubsSorted(to.params.pmid_list);
    }
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    next()
  }
  ,

Answer (score -1):

You can try to watch your route changes.

```
watch:{
    '$route.params.pmid_list': function (pmid_list) {
        //your logic here
    }
},
```